# UnknownError: Permission denied to access property "__raven__"

Tags: angularjs, node.js, protractor, end-to-end

I was running my tests locally and everything was fine. In the development environment, I get the Stacktrace message:

> UnknownError: Permission denied access to property "__raven __".

This was shortly after the Protractor simply capture an element with a id in particular.

`expect(element(by.id('test-side-custom')).isPresent()).toBeTruthy();`

If I repeat the same command in `it()` next, it works.

Any idea?

Comment: I am getting the same error, any solutions. It only happens in firefox

Comment: I'm getting this locally as well.

Comment: Submitted a ticket with Raven: https://github.com/getsentry/raven-js/issues/495

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to find a temporary workaround. The problem seems to be caused by an attempt to set properties on the native `window.addEventListener` function. Not sure why this is only a problem when running tests. The workaround involves modifying the `wrap` function in raven.js. Find the following `if` statement around line `249`:

```
// We don't wanna wrap it twice!
if (func.__raven__) {
    return func;
}
```

Then add the following try...catch block to prevent the error condition:

```
try {
  func.__raven__;
  func.__raven_wrapper__;
} catch (e) {
  return func;
}
```

I have updated the github issue with this workaround. Let's see what they say.